# How to generate self-signed certificate for App Transport Security

Tags: ios9, app-transport-security

I would like to generate my own SSL certificate for my iOS app communication with server.
I suppose, it's normal use in this case self-signed certificate.

I tried to create certificate using the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out astro.key
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out astro.crt
```

But my app don't like to work with server: I have following error:

**NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)**

In [Apple ATS technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) I can find following list of supported ciphers:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

I'am not very good in cryptography, and I suppose, I generated a wrong key and certificate.

Could anybody please advise me, how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9 self-signed certificates are not allowed. Your cert should be fine.

Just add the following to your Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yourdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this site to verify if your certificate is ok or not  [sslabs.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). Here an example of twitter API  [results](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.twitter.com&s=199.59.148.87) ...Your server SSL report should look like this more or less.